# How can i solve search issue in civiCRM?

Tags: custom-search

In Wordpress I create two forms: one for a teacher and a second for a student. I need to search for teacher data using the student search form. But I can't understand how to do it. Please give solution, how can i solve this issue?

Comment: It helps if you add the version of CiviCRM you are using and give a little more detail on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: civiCRM version is 4.6 . my first time working with civiCRM . i create two profiles one for add data of students and second for teachers. after that use some fields as searchable and create two new page first for teacher search and second for student search. but search is not working for me dont know why. please help. i want working functionality of search

Comment: do you mean that when someone fills in the Student Form you need them to have a field that will reference the Teacher? if so perhaps you could try a Contact Reference field

Comment: my issue is using teacher search form need to search saved teachers data. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but if you are coding you could use the CiviCRM API to first find the teacher for the student with the API Relationship/Getsingle and then find the data for the teacher with the API Contact/Getsingle?

Aer you familiar with using the CiviCRM API? If not, explanation can be found on the documentation wiki: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API

Comment: is there any way to add search functionality from admin end or only solution is API ?

Comment: I am not used to working with profiles on Wordpress, afraid I can not help ypu there. But I am sure there will be others who can :-)